# How to retrieve and display data in local storage from an array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

How do I get the item.title, item.price, item.imageScr values and set them to variables I can use in `displayCart()`

I am saving an array of information with those three values with the key item.
but I want to display that information in my shopping cart.
And i don't know in what way how to display that information and pass it in to display cart.

```
var product = [
  {
    title: title,
    price: price,
    image: imageSrc
  }
];
var pods = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item")) || [];
pods.push(product);
localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(pods));
//displayCart(title, price, imageSrc)
saveCart();

function loadCart() {
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    displayCart();
  }
}

function displayCart() {
  //var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item"))[0]
  var cartRow = document.createElement("div");
  cartRow.classList.add("cart-row");
  var cartItems = document.getElementsByClassName("cart-items")[0];
  var cartRowContents = `
        <div class="cart-row">
  <div class="cart-column cart-item" style="padding-top: 1%">
    <img class="image" style="width: 25%;" src="${imageSrc}" alt="" />
    <h2 style="padding-left: 5%">${title}</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-column cart-price" style="padding-top: 1%">
    <h2 class="price">${price}</h2>
  </div>
  <form class="cart-column cart-quantity">
    <input
      class="quantity"
      type="number"
      id="number"
      value="1"
      style="width: 15%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: 60%"
    />
  </form>
  <span style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button " type="button">
      Remove
    </button>
  </span>
</div>`;

  cartRow.innerHTML = cartRowContents;
  cartItems.append(cartRow);
  cartRow
    .getElementsByClassName("btn-primary")[0]
    .addEventListener("click", RemoveCartItem);
  saveCart();
}
```

I would assume I could just get the item.value and use that as a reference to displaying the price,title and image but that doesn't work.

Comment: Pass around the relevant things as parameters to the functions. So `displayCart()` should take a product object as a parameter and use that. `loadCart()` should include the `localStorage.getItem()` part above it so it can pass the correct object into `displayCart()`. So you should change the code to first extract everything from local back into the products array. Then loop the products array instead of the localStorage. So your commented away `displayCart(title, price, imageSrc)` is actually the correct idea.

Comment: PS: var product is an array. So if you write an array to local, you get an array back. So the title is actually inside `pods[0].title` instead.

Comment: @Shilly wait could you give me a code example?
I think i get what you mean. But if i displayCart takes in the product object how can it also take in title,price and imageScr?

And to your PS. that makes sense! So i should be able to do `pods[0].title = title` to get the title of the product right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of what I meant in my comments. Apart from the selectors, we pass in all the relevant data into the function.

So the render() function takes the collection it has to render, the place where it has to render, and an extra.

The event handlers take in the event object.

You notice that the functions that do not take parameters, fetch_cart(), is a function that actually returns something.

Now you can use all of these to write a document.onload function that will use the render function with whatever parameters you want.

ps: localStorage does not work with stack snippets, so I copy/pasted and tested in chrome.

```js
const stock = [
  { "id": 1, "title": "shoes", "price": 99.99, "image": "/path/1.png", "available": 75 },
  { "id": 2, "title": "shirt", "price": 67.14, "image": "/path/2.png", "available": 2  },
  { "id": 3, "title": "shoes", "price": 85.25, "image": "/path/3.png", "available": 0  },
  { "id": 4, "title": "hats",  "price": 15.2,  "image": "/path/4.png", "available": 18 }
];

const render = ( collection, list, button_type ) => {
  const items = collection.map( item => `
 <li>
   <span>${ item.title }</span>
   <span>${ item.price }</span>
   <span>${ item.available }</span>
   <button data-type="${ button_type }" data-reference="${ item.id }">${ button_type }</button>
 </li>
  `);
  list.innerHTML += items.join( '' );
};

const fetch_cart = () => {
  return Array.from({ length: localStorage.length - 1 }, ( _, index ) => {
 const item_key = localStorage.key( index );
 return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( item_key ));
  });
};

const add_to_cart = event => {
  const id = parseInt( event.target.getAttribute( 'data-reference' ), 10 );
  const item = stock.find( item => item.id === id );
  if ( !item.available > 0 ) alert( 'item is sold out' );
  else {
 item.available -= 1;
 const clone = Object.assign({}, item );
 localStorage.setItem( `order_${ Date.now() }`, JSON.stringify( clone ));
 render( [ clone ], list_cart, 'delete' );
  }
};

const delete_from_cart = event => {
  console.log( 'TODO' );
  // basically the reverse of add_to_cart
};

const list_stock = document.querySelector( '#stock' );
const list_cart = document.querySelector( '#cart' );

list_stock.addEventListener( 'click', add_to_cart );

list_cart.addEventListener( 'click', delete_from_cart );

render( stock, list_stock, 'add' );
render( fetch_cart(), list_cart, 'delete' );
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<label>Your order</label>
 <ul id="cart"></ul>
 <label>Available</label>
 <ul id="stock"></ul>
```

Comment: Man you're an angel, thanks! the example really helped me to understand everything.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the item inside the `loadCart` function & on each iteration pass the element.

```
 function loadCart() {
    let lcStr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('itemName'));
    for (var i = 0; i < lcStr.length; i++){
        displayCart(lcStr[i]);
    }
  }
```

You need to make slight change in the `displayCart` function

Comment: well that's fine but I want to pass all the values inside the item. And use them in my HTML element